# Job-Shop problem variant: given timespan, maximize how many jobs i can perform

Tags: python, optimization, scheduling, mixed-integer-programming, operations-research

I found many variants of the Job Shop Problem, but not the following one, and it looks like pretty useful in pratical scenarios

1. given a timespan (one year for example)
2. n machines
3. the structure of the job (machine, duration), but NOT the amount of jobs.

the goal is to produce a scheduling which maximizes the amount of jobs i can execute in the assigned timespan. I think it's a pretty common situation in which i want to create a scheduling to maximize the production.
Unfortunately i cannot figure out how to model the problem,
An example, a literature reference or a direction towards i can investigate further would be much appreciated.

Regards,
Luca

Comment: You would probably have more luck on the Operations Research part of stack exchange. Asking for external references is off-topic here. That said, OR-Tools will already handle this for you, or you can look at the stuff on my website (linked on my profile) which includes some code that could be adapted to something like this (though, there'll be effort involved in adapting it and the documentation isn't great as I never find the time :'( )

Comment: @roganjosh, Joel had already posted this on the Google OR forum, the examples apparently don't apply to his problem.

Comment: yes, but the @roganjosh's s website is really helpful